# How can I conditionally instantiate a member object to exhibit different behaviors depending on parent object?

Tags: c++, oop, templates, template-meta-programming

I'm creating two objects of struct `Player`, each with a `pawn` container. I want this member to be defined with a different type depending on the `Player` object it is in, such that `white.pawn.say()` and `black.pawn.say` exhibit different behaviors. I've tried making `WhitePawn` and `BlackPawn` classes respectively, but I don't know of a factory design pattern that will allow me to instantiate member objects inside of a class.

```cpp
template <bool N> struct Pawn : public Piece {
    Pawn(U64 bb) : Piece(bb, 1) {};
};
template <> struct Pawn<0> : public Piece {
    void say(U64 x) {
        std::cout << "White pawns" << (x << 8) << "\n";
    }
};
template <> struct Pawn<1> : public Piece {
    void say(U64 x) {
        std::cout << "Black pawns" << (x >> 8) << "\n";
    }
};

struct Player {
    Pawn<color> pawn; // Expected compile-time constant expression
    Knight knight;
    Bishop bishop;

    Player(U64 p, U64 n, U64 b, bool color)
        : pawn(p)
        , knight(n)
        , bishop(b)
    {};
};

Player white(
    0xFF000000000000, //   pawns
    0x4200000000000000, // knights
    0x2400000000000000, // bishops
    0 // color (white)
);

Player black(
    0xFF00, // pawns
    0x42, //   knights
    0x24, //   bishops
    1 // color (black)
);
```

I don't want to make `Player` a templated struct because it is called as a datatype later on. (`int makeMove(Player& own, Player& enemy, U16 move) {...`) Is there perhaps a way to make convert `color` to a constant expression so the compiler picks up on it? What's the best way to go about conditionally instantiating member objects of different types for different parent objects?

Comment: Either make it a template (static dispatch) or make it a virtual subclass (dynamic dispatch). Those are the two ways you can get polymorphic behavior in C++. Pick one.

Comment: *"I want this member to be defined with a different type depending on the Player object it is in"* -- this is impossible, as all objects of the same type must have the same types for all of their data members. I could post this as an answer, but do you want a chance to rewrite your question so that this requirement of yours is no longer a blocker? Currently, you have "different type" as your requirement and "exhibit different behaviors" as the side-effect. A rewrite could make "exhibit different behaviors" your requirement and "different type" merely your failed attempt at your goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, you're sure that there are only a given number of possible classes to choose from. This is called discriminated union in type systems and can be represented using a variant:

Example code:

```
struct Player {
    using PawnType = std::variant<Pawn<0>, Pawn<1>>;
    PawnType pawn;
    Knight knight;
    Bishop bishop;

    Player(U64 p, U64 n, U64 b, bool color)
        : pawn(color ? PawnType(Pawn<1>(p)) : PawnType(Pawn<0>(p))
        , knight(n)
        , bishop(b)
    {};
};
```

Usage of `pawn` at this point requires writing a visitor:

```
auto v = [&](auto&& pawn) {
    /* here goes the code accessing the actual Pawn<0> or Pawn<1> as pawn */
};
std::visit(v, player.pawn);
```

E.g., instead of `white.pawn.say(x);`, you'd  write:

```
auto v = [&](auto&& actualPawn) {
    actualPawn.say(x);
}; // this is a visitor

std::visit(v, white.pawn);
```

or, in case of such a small visitor, you can write in one line:

```
std::visit([&](auto&& actualPawn) { actualPawn.say(x) }, white.pawn);
```

Comment: Apologies, `std::variant` and `std::visit` are new to me so I am researching them now. I take it `std::variant` allows for the instantiation of an object with multiple datatypes, but the implementation of `std::visit` is beyond me. Can you provide an example of how I might call `white.pawn.say(x)`?

Comment: @IsaacChugunov Updated the answer with an example. The idea is, `std::visit(v, o);` goes from `std::variant<T1, T2, ...>& o` to the actual type `Ti& actualO` and calls `v(actualO)`. Basically, you can go from an either-or type to the concrete type.